# expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:

Tags: javabeans, autowired

I am trying  to use multiple datasource from a springboot application using Spring data jpa repository and  to call the repository method in a spring rest controller/service, wan not able to call repository method. Please find my classes below and suggest appropriate solution.

```java
// define the service layer to call the repository
public TestService{
    @Autowired
    private xyRepository xyzRepo;
// Not able to autowire the 

xyzRepo.findAll();

//REpository class

public interface xyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SiteEntity,String>{

{
    //call the API method
}
```

```
/***Application.properties***/

#production DataBase
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://cdef.com:1435;DatabaseName=tttt
spring.datasource.username = reader
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxxxx


#production DataBase for PGSEO DB
spring.abcdatasource.driver-class-name= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.abcdatasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://xyz.com:1436;DatabaseName=abc
spring.abcdatasource.username = xyz
spring.abcdatasource.password = xxxxxx


#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

server.port = 9595

# Naming strategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=false
```

```java
//1st java config file

package com.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "eoianalyticEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "eoianalyticTransactionManager", 
        basePackages = "com.sample.jparepository.primary" /*** Give the JPA repository location for eoi analytic DB**/
)
public class EOIAnalyticConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource springDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .build();
    }
    /**
     * Entity manager definition. 
     *  
     * @param builder an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
     * @return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "eoianalyticEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean eoianalyticEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                    .dataSource(springDataSource())
                    .properties(hibernateProperties())
                    .packages("com.sample.entity.primary")
                    .persistenceUnit("eoianalyticpu")
                    .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "eoianalyticTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager eoianalyticTransactionManager(@Qualifier("eoianalyticEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");

        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                                                        e -> e.getValue())
                                                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }

}
```

```java
//2nd config file for second datasource

package com.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "abcEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "pgseoTransactionManager", 
        basePackages = "com.sample.jparepository.secondary"/**** Provide the secondary repository package name*******/
)
public class PGSEOConfig {
        /**
         * PGSEO datasource definition.
         * 
         * @return datasource.
         */
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.abcdatasource")
        public DataSource pgseoDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder
                        .create()
                        .build();
        }
        /**
         * Entity manager definition. 
         *  
         * @param builder an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
         * @return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
         */
        @Bean(name = "pgseoEntityManager")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pgseoEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                        .dataSource(pgseoDataSource())
                        .properties(hibernateProperties())
                        .packages("com.sample.entity.secondary")
                        .persistenceUnit("pgseoPU")
                        .build();
        }
        /**
         * @param entityManagerFactory
         * @return
         */
        @Bean(name = "pgseoTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager pgseoTransactionManager(@Qualifier("pgseoEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }
        private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("config/"+"application.properties");
            try {
                Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
                return properties.entrySet().stream()
                                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                            e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                                                            e -> e.getValue())
                                                        );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return new HashMap<String, Object>();
            }
        }

}
```

```java
---------------------------------------------------------
//POM.xml file 

package com.sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages=("com.sample.*"))
@EntityScan(basePackages = ("com.sample.entity.*"))
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MultipleDataSourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultipleDataSourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MultipleDataSource</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4-4.0</version>  
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: read about how autowiring works http://codegeekslab.com/autowiring-using-annotations-spring/

Comment: Thanks saurabh ! for the annotation detail .